# how to sort table with form option in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

i want to sorting table with user input (form option)

i have this in my view :

```
<select name="orderby" id="orderby">
    <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
    <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
```

controller :

```
 public function status()
{
    $dosen = DB::table('dosen')->orderBy('status')->paginate(7);
    return view('dosen.status', compact('dosen'));
}
```

how to change sort table to desc when user click "Descending" or "Ascending" option?

Comment: Use AJAX if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Ajax, you could always use Laravel's collection methods. They're extremely powerful once you start using them fluently.

In your example, you could simply eliminate the orderBy clause and use the sortBy() and sortByDesc() methods depending on user input.

You could then use the chunk() method to create your own pagination. Using your example, to sort all rows for the 'dosen' table in descending order in groups of 7 chunks:

```
$dosen = DB::table('dosen')->get();     

$dosenSortedDesc = $dosen->sortByDesc('status')->chunk(7);
```